# CSS Nesting counters: UL inside OL count

Tags: css, css-counter

It is easy to get the correct count if ol inside ol the format looks like below

```
 <ol>
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item             
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>     
      <li>item</li>    
      <li>item          
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>        
  <li>item</li>      
  <li>item
     <ol>
      <li>item</li>      
      <li>item</li>      
      <li>item         
    </ol>
   </li>        
  <li>item</li>       
</ol>
```

However, if I want to put ul inside ol I can't get counter works correctly

```
  <ol>
  <li>item</li> 
  <li>item             
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>     
      <li>item</li>    
      <li>item          
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>        
  <li>item</li>      
  <li>item
     <ul>
      <li>item</li>      
      <li>item</li>      
      <li>item         
    </ul>
   </li>        
  <li>item</li>       
</ol>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaxymnh8/

[image]

Is there a way to avoid counting ul ?

Comment: You're missing closing `</li>` tags on the final list items in the sublists (item 5 and 11)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a very simple way to fix it. Just use a CSS child selector (`>`) so the count only includes `<li>`s that are children of the `<ol>`.

```
ol > li::before {
  counter-increment: my;
  content: counter(my) ; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaxymnh8/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a counter to the sub `li`

so this is how you would do it

```
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
.count{
    counter-reset: section;
}

ol>li {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

ol>li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) ". ";
}

ul li:before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_dever/guhgpwgh/1/)

Comment: No need for all this code :) Take a look at my answer below (unless I've missed something!)